# Os valores de output estão saindo sem espaço

Tags: python, dicionário, input-output

Tenho o seguinte problema para resolver:

> Criptografia (em grego: kryptós, "escondido", e gráphein, "escrita") é o estudo dos princípios e técnicas pelas quais a informação pode ser transformada da sua forma original para outra ilegível, de forma que possa ser conhecida apenas por seu destinatário (detentor da "chave secreta"), o que a torna difícil de ser lida por alguém não autorizado (Wikipédia).
>
> Uma das técnicas simples de criptografia é o da cifra de substituição, que é composto de:
>
> Alfabeto normal;
>
> Alfabeto para a cifragem;
>
> A mensagem cifrada
>
> Como resultado do processo de descriptografia temos a mensagem original.
>   Implemente, então, um programa que dados estes 3 componentes retorne a mensagem original. Cada um destes componentes está numa linha distinta.

Para resolver o problema, codifiquei o seguinte algoritmo:

```
def descriptografar_texto(alfabeto_normal,alfabeto_cifrado,mensagem):    
    dic = {}
    alfa_norm = list(alfabeto_normal)
    alfa_cifr = list(alfabeto_cifrado)
    frase = ''
    for letra1,letra2 in zip(alfa_cifr,alfa_norm):
        dic[letra1] = letra2
    for letra in mensagem:
        if letra in dic:
            frase += dic.get(letra)
    return frase

a = input()
b = input()
c = input()

print(descriptografar_texto(a,b,c))
```

A saída desejada é uma frase, entretanto, a minha saída está saindo sem espaços entre as palavras.
Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: A postagem foi arrumada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei um `else` para quando a `letra` não estiver no dicionário ele colocar um espaço.

```
if letra in dic:            
                frase += dic.get(letra)
            else:
                frase += " "
```

Segue o código completo:

```
def descriptografar_texto(alfabeto_normal,alfabeto_cifrado,mensagem):

    dic = {}
    alfa_norm = list(alfabeto_normal)
    alfa_cifr = list(alfabeto_cifrado)
    frase = ''
    for letra1,letra2 in zip(alfa_cifr,alfa_norm):
        dic[letra1] = letra2
    for letra in mensagem:
        if letra in dic:            
            frase += dic.get(letra)
        else:
            frase += " "

    return frase

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

b = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'm', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']

c = "mlhhz jfv olfxfiz"

print(descriptografar_texto(a,b,c))
```

Saída:

`nossa que loucura`

Comment: Note que eu coloquei o alfabeto minúsculo então se você digitar uma letra maiúscula será exibido um espaço. O mesmo acontece para números e caracteres especiais. Para corrigir isto as listas `a` e `b` precisam ser atualizadas.

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Que ótimo, fico muito feliz em te ajudar. Abraço e até a próxima!